# Search and replace in print composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, replace

I made a print layout with servales pages with the QGIS print composer and added some text to the layout, like the project name etc.

Is there a fast way to change the project name in all pages?

Like a "search and replace" or do I have to change it manually in all pages?

Comment: I guess you'll have to do this manually. Next time you could use `@project_basename` so it will adapt automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to do that: save your project as qgs file (not the default zipped qgz file). Than open this qgs file and search/replace there - be sure to let everything elso untouched. Save your changes, close and open the qgs file again: the changes should be refeflected in your print composer.

When doing so, you could use a variable for the project name as proposed by @Erik. Than you cand handly easily within QGIS for further changes.

Comment: No need to save as a .QGS file as .QGZ are just compressed version. you just need to change the .qgz by .zip, open the now zip archive and do your change then change back to .qgz

Comment: OK, great to know that.